# Why ViewPagerIndicator calculate all titles every time

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using ViewPager and ViewPagerIndicator [(here)](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). WHen I debug, I see that the ViewPagerIndicator call `getPageTitle()` to get title of all pages every time I scroll the Viewpager. Now I have more then 1000 pages. So, when I scroll, the titles aren't smooth any more. Did you face this problem before? Please share with me the solution. Any recommend are welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: IMHO, `ViewPager` is inappropriate for 1,000 pages. The user is not going to swipe through 1,000 pages, or even fling through 1,000 tabs.

Comment: But in some special case we maybe let user scroll to 1000 pages. And the problem is that the ViewPagerIndicator re-calculate all titles of 1000 pages. That's not good. Right?

Comment: "That's not good" -- then grab the source code for ViewPagerIndicator and change it to work how you wish. Or try `PagerTabStrip`. Or write your own tab implementation from scratch. Or avoid the use of tabs altogether.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue, I have a `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter`. Each time I scroll back to the page, the list keeps recreating it self and expands.. I solved it with a simple `boolean` to check weather the list have items or not, but that's not the optimum solution. I think there is something in `OnPageChangeListener` from android.support.v4.view.ViewPager package that ViewPagerIndicator doesn't address.